# Nikto result, i don't get it

Tags: security

I am currently scanning a webapplication with Nikto in order to find flaws. I am getting quite a few errors such as these:

```
/backup.tar.bz2: Potentially interesting archive/cert file found. (NOTE: requested by IP address).
```

If i visit the url listed above in a browser, nothing happens and it is blocked, but i am still curious on what is happening here. I could not find a good answer by searching... (Google/stackoverflow/various blogs).

As i see it, the application is not accepting a request here, also Apache is not giving a request result.

Hopefully somebody here could help me out

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, it's just about disabling certain file downloads.

Answer (score -1):

While running,

```
nikto -h "Web Server"
```

Look up for an architecture, for eg... Do you see "Samba",etc?
If yes, go to exploit-db and type the architecture...
For samba there's one called "openfuck.c", :Sorry, but that is the name:
Also, apache doesn't give request the way you are doing it, you should know how to use netcat for that.